# Django ORM get each group's latest data

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, group-by

I want to get specific user's all terms, latest agreement data.
Three is terms table which has terms name.
In table TermsAgreeHistory, there exists users agreement history

```
class TermsAgreeHistory(model.Model):
    user = models.CharField()
    terms = models.ForeignKey(Terms)
    date_signed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_agreed = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Terms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

terms is foreign key

```
         TermsAgreeHistory
pk  user   terms   data_signed   is_agreed
----------------------------------------
1   Jack     1      20-01-01         Y
2   Jack     1      19-01-01         Y
3   Jack     2      20-01-01         N
4   Jack     2      19-01-01         N
5   Jack     3      20-01-01         Y
6   SAM      3      20-01-01         Y
```

Under table has terms catalog

```
       Terms
 pk         name
 --------------------     
 1       member_term   
 2       search_term
 3       share_term
```

I want to search Jack's latest agreement and signed-date of terms which is in Terms table.
By using Django ORM.

```
              result
----------------------------------------
1   Jack     member_term   20-01-01         Y
3   Jack     search_term   20-01-01         N
5   Jack     share_term    20-01-01         Y
```

Most important thing is my db is mysql -> can not use distinct method on column.
How should I write code?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda ugly and slow, but this is the best way I've found.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Subquery, OuterRef

terms_history = TermsAgreeHistory.objects\
    .filter(terms_id=OuterRef("terms_id")\
    .order_by("-id")\
    .values("id")[:1]
newest = TermsAgreeHistory.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(terms_history))
terms = Terms.objects\
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch("termsagreehistory_set", queryset=newest, to_attr="newest_history")
    )\
    .all()
```

If you need it to be really fast, you can look into putting a trigger in your DB to store the most recent `TermsAgreeHistory` for each `Terms`: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/243988/186435